# this.functionName is not a function - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my reactJS app, I've function that calls a helper function to get some calculation's result. Here is my component;

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";

class drawImage extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.mounted = true;
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.mounted = false;
  }

  //here is my helper function in same `jsx` file;

  calculateX = (x, y) => {
    return x + y;
  };

  //here is my parent function in `jsx` file;

  attachCircle = (svgRef: SVGElement) => {
    //some code, and then I call function like this...
    var x = 10;
    var y = 20;
    var result = this.calculateX(x, y);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          version="1.1"
          className="draw-image"
          ref={this.attachCircle}
        ></svg>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

so when I run this, my app got crashed by displaying this error

> TypeError: this.calculateX is not a function

and if I call it like this;

```
var res = this.calculateX;
```

it does nothing.. no error, no result.

**Can anyone help me out what I'm missing here? because I need to pass params as well.**

Comment: You need to show how your component looks like.

Comment: Did you bind your function? i.e.  ```this.calculateX = this.calculateX.bind(this);```

Comment: @Clarity component added..

Comment: @MickVader how will I pass parameters then??

Comment: I didn't see your full component before commenting. Maybe add in a constructor at the top of your component like so:  

```constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.calculateX = this.calculateX.bind(this);
}```

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: @MickVader constructor added, still same error

Comment: Keep the constructor and try changing ```ref={this.attachCircle}``` to ```ref={this.attachCircle.bind(this)}```

Comment: Code doesn't seem to have any issues when tested in sandbox

Comment: @MickVader tried.. still same error

Comment: @ChristopherNgo yes code is correct, I dont know why is it not working..

Comment: I did put a fast codesandbox and there is no issues in the code at all.
@NullPointer https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-water-umtok Everything here is correct.

Comment: @DamianBusz let me add complete component in runnable code section..

Comment: @DamianBusz I did add some code in your codesandbox, it is not giving any error but neither providing any result. Check the console

Comment: @NullPointer Link me the sandbox cause its possible you got a new link, regardless of this I still dont understand what you want to do with this calculateX, its simply not clear.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to draw circle on click and then I do some further calculations to draw lines (something like crosshair). Everything works well if I put those calculations within same function, but as I've to reuse those again n again, so i put them in helper function, and now when i call that function, it gives stated error. I added simple calculation in question code to avoid any confusion. Actual issue is with function calling.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-nash-qfe3r check it, if you click on output window's left side, it will display coordinates, and then it should call function and display 'x' in console (as added in helper function), but it is not displaying it..

Comment: There are 2 problems: you're calling calculateY and you're inside a subfunction so `this` value changes. Just put `var _this = this` before and use `_this`. Check it: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-merkle-bw63j?fontsize=14

Comment: @TheDeveloper answer is correct

Comment: @TheDeveloper Yes.. now it is working fine.... thanks a lot Man..

Comment: @DamianBusz Yes, it worked finally.. thanks for bearing with me..

Comment: @TheDeveloper do add it as an answer.. so I can accept it..it may help someone else..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-nash-qfe3r).

There are 2 problems:

1) you're calling calculateY instead of calculateX

2) you're inside a subfunction so `this` value changes.

Just put `var _this = this` before and use `_this`.

Check it [here](http://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-merkle-bw63j?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesnt have any issue. But I would recommend you do something like this.

If you are using babel you need to target your preset to es2015

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-es2015-destructuring",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    ["transform-class-properties", { "spec": true }]
  ]
}
```

If you are using  `create-react-app` it will take care everything for you

Also follow coding convention when create es6 class like this

```
class LoginForm extends Component
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably should write `attachCircle.bind(this)` where you call `attachCircle`.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE:** ignore this answer. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57688718/3629772).

From [official doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html):

> You have to be careful about the meaning of this in JSX callbacks. In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to bind this.handleClick and pass it to onClick, this will be undefined when the function is actually called.
>
> This is not React-specific behavior; it is a part of how functions work in JavaScript. Generally, if you refer to a method without () after it, such as onClick={this.handleClick}, you should bind that method.

So you have to add in your component constructor:

```
this.calculateX = this.calculateX.bind(this);
```

Comment: @mick suggested this in comments, and I've added this but still getting same error

Comment: Nice reading of the comment section. If you kept reading he said that didn't work.

Comment: I just read. Well, it should work. Post an example of the code so we can run it, for example with repl or jsfiddle.

Comment: You don't have to bind arrow functions. There are no class methods and the quote is irrelevant.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. I tested it too and it seems to work as you wrote so maybe some problem with your client like cache or similiars?. Make a fiddle or try it in another environment and check if it works.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-surf-fvzmo?fontsize=14 I only added some line for debugging and changed "drawImage" to "DrawImage". It works.

Comment: Check my comment on the question, I cloned your codesandbox and it works, I see a point when you click

Comment: checked and it worked like a charm.. Thanks dude.. do change your answer or add an other answer same like your comment so that I can accept it